# Is it possible to to use same frequency band and same frequency blocks for two adjacent/near telecom circles

Tags: rf, radio, telecommunications, spectrum

As shown in the Screen-Shot, TRAI (Telecom Regulatory authority of India) in the pre-auction recommendation manual to DoT(Department of telecommunication) mentions 770 MHz of the spectrum ( 35 MHz for all 22 telecom circles in India) up for auction. *But using the same frequency band in all telecom circles or two adjacent circles leads to interference.* Even then they are being recommended for auctioning what am I missing? Please help me understand. I am using telecom circle for LSA (licensed service area)in the screenshot. [image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Can you justify this: *But using the same frequency band in all telecom circles or two adjacent circles leads to interference.*

Answer (score 0):

A "licensed service area" is a licensing fee division, not a technical division. "Andhra Pradesh" is a LSA. You may compare to "France" and "Germany".  France and Germany are adjacent, and both use the same Bands for mobile telecommunications.  That doesn't "lead to interference".

Using the same bands for adjacent mobile towers (a much much smaller area) doesn't "lead to interference". Thousands or millions of mobile phones may use the same bands in the same LSA. That doesn't "lead to interference". because interference is a technical problem, addressed by things like antenna direction and signal coding.